# How to call methods cyclically using a timer?

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
internal class BuzzerStateTimedProcessor
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private bool _executed = true;

    public BuzzerStateTimedProcessor()
    {
        _timer = new( OnTimer );
    }

    private void DurationOn()
        => Console.WriteLine( "duration on" );

    private void DurationOff()
        => Console.WriteLine( "duration off" );

    private TimeSpan _durationOff;
    private TimeSpan _durationOn;
    private TimeSpan _cycles;
    private TimeSpan _repeatCount;
    public void DurationCycle(
        TimeSpan? duration,
        TimeSpan durationOn,
        TimeSpan durationOff )
    {
        _durationOff = durationOff;
        _durationOn = durationOn;

        var permanentOperation = !duration.HasValue;

        if ( permanentOperation )
        {
            _timer.Change( TimeSpan.Zero, durationOn );
        }
        else
        {
            _cycles = TimeSpan.Zero;
            _repeatCount = duration.Value;

            /// some logic
        }
    }

    private void OnTimer( object state )
    {
        if ( _executed )
            DurationOn();
        else
            DurationOff();

        _executed = !_executed;
    }
}
```

I can use it this way:

```
var test = new BuzzerStateTimedProcessor();
test.DurationCycle(null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) );
```

**The result:**
**DurationOn()**,
** waiting for 2 seconds,
**DurationOff()**,
** waiting for 2 seconds,
**DurationOn()**,
** waiting for 2 seconds,
**DurationOff()**,
** waiting for 2 seconds
etc

ok, now I would like to call commands cyclically for 10 seconds. How can I do this?
I wanna set 10 seconds as parameter and do some logic

```
var test = new BuzzerStateTimedProcessor();
test.DurationCycle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) );
```

Comment: Have a look at `PeriodicTimer`

Comment: timer from System.Threading; is good too. I just want to understand the logic

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the goal is to turn on something on for a set amount of time, then turn it off for a (different) set amount of time. There seem to be a whole lot other things going on in the posted code that I'm just going to ignore.

You do not seem to be that far of, but you should probably call `.Change` again in the event handler:

```
private bool isOn;
public void DurationCycle( TimeSpan durationOn, TimeSpan durationOff )
{
    // store variables, create timer etc.

    // Set the timer to only tick once
    timer.Change(durationOff, Timeout.Infinite);
}

private void OnTimer( object state )
{
    isOn = !isOn;
    if (isOn)
       DurationOn();
    else
       DurationOff();

    // Setup the timer for the next tick
    var nextDueTime = isOn ? durationOn : durationOff;
    timer.Change(nextDueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

So calling this with 1s on 2 s off should produce

```
// pause for 2s
duration on
// pause for 1s
duration off
// pause for 2s
etc.
```